# How to create a sequence of integers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, sequence

F# has *sequences* that allows to create sequences:

```
seq { 0 .. 10 }
```

Create sequence of numbers from 0 to 10.

Is there something similar in C#?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range(0, 10);`. Example:

```
var seq = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
```

MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx).

Comment: Note: This creates a sequence starting at 0 with 10 items (ending at 9). If you want 0 *through* 10, the second parameter would be 11. And if you need an actual array and not `IEnumerable<int>`, include a call `.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 43):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 11);
```

Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx

Answer (score 20):

You could create a simple function. This would work for a more complicated sequence. Otherwise the `Enumerable.Range` should do.

```
IEnumerable<int> Sequence(int n1, int n2)
{
    while (n1 <= n2)
    {
        yield return  n1++;
    }
}
```

Comment: By "more complicated" do you mean just "where you have begin and end handy instead of the number of elements"? Otherwise I'm missing your meaning. 

Comment: I believe I was considering `OddSequence` `EvenSequence` or other custom ranges. `if (++n1 % 2 == 0) yield return n1`, for example. It's been a few days ;)

Comment: Ha, yeah, one or two days I suppose. Or a few thousand. ;^)

Answer (score 11):

Linq projection with the rarely used [indexer overload (i)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__):

```
(new int[11]).Select((o,i) => i)
```

I prefer this method for its flexibilty.

For example, if I want evens:

```
(new int[11]).Select((item,i) => i*2)
```

Or if I want 5 minute increments of an hour:

```
(new int[12]).Select((item,i) => i*5)
```

Or strings:

```
(new int[12]).Select((item,i) => "Minute:" + i*5)
```

Comment: I really like this but it also feels a bit hacky at the same time!

Comment: lol :-) It's just a great creative use of the indexer overload!

Comment: I feel like doing  `Enumerable.Range(0, 12).Select( i => "Minute:" + i*5 )` is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 8.0 you can use [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

For example:

```
var seq = 0..2;
var array = new string[]
{
    "First",
    "Second",
    "Third",
};

foreach(var s in array[seq])
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
}
// Output: First, Second
```

Or if you want create `IEnumerable<int>` then you can use extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ToEnumerable(this Range range)
{
   for (var i = range.Start.Value; i < range.End.Value; i++)
   {
       yield return i;
   }
}
...
var seq = 0..2;

foreach (var s in seq.ToEnumerable())
{
   System.Console.WriteLine(s);
}
// Output: 0, 1
```

P.S. But be careful with *'indexes from end'*. For example, ToEnumerable extension method is not working with `var seq = ^2..^0`.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation:

```
    private static IEnumerable<int> Sequence(int start, int end)
    {
        switch (Math.Sign(end - start))
        {
            case -1:
                while (start >= end)
                {
                    yield return start--;
                }

                break;

            case 1:
                while (start <= end)
                {
                    yield return start++;
                }

                break;

            default:
                yield break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Originally [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19949875/659190).

---

If you want to enumerate a sequence of numbers (`IEnumerable<int>`) from `0` to a `10`, then try

```
Enumerable.Range(0, ++10);
```

In explanation, to get a sequence of numbers from 0 to 10, you want the sequence to start at 0 (remembering that there are 11 numbers between 0 and 10, inclusive).

---

If you want an unlimited linear series, you could write a function like

```
IEnumerable<int> Series(int k = 0, int n = 1, int c = 1)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return k;
        k = (c * k) + n;
    }
}
```

which you could use like

```
var ZeroTo10 = Series().Take(11);
```

---

If you want a function you can call repeatedly to generate incrementing numbers, perhaps you want somthing like.

```
using System.Threading;

private static int orderNumber = 0;

int Seq()
{
    return Interlocked.Increment(ref orderNumber);
}
```

When you call `Seq()` it will return the next order number and increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

I have these functions in my code

```
private static IEnumerable<int> FromZero(this int count)
    {
        if (count <= 0)
            yield break;

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> FromOne(this int count)
    {
        if (count <= 0)
            yield break;

        for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
```

This helps to reduce some for(i) code.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wish to also save the generated sequence in a variable:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<int> numbersToPrint = Enumerable.Range(1, 11);
```

This is implicit in other solutions shown above, but I am also explicitly including the needed namespaces for this to work as expected.