# LINQ to create int array of sequential numbers

Tags: asp.net, linq

So instead of writing a looping function where you instantiate an array and then set each index value as the index, is there a way to do this in LINQ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create array with sequence of integers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588787/how-to-create-array-with-sequence-of-integers-in-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range(0, 10)` will give you an `IEnumerable<int>` containing zero to 9.

Comment: Actually that would be "zero to 9".  The second parameter is a count.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`System.Linq.Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) method for this purpose.

> Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.

For example:

```
var zeroToNineArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();
```

will create an array of sequential integers with values in the inclusive range [0, 9].

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at [Enumberable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)

```
For Each( var i in Enumberable.Range(1,5).ToArray()){
    Console.WriteLine(i)
}
```

would print out 1,2,3,4,5