# Create c# int[] with value as 0,1,2,3... length

Tags: c#, arrays

I like to create an `int[]` with length `X` and value it with [0,1,2....X]

e.g.

`public int[] CreateAA(int X){}`

`int[] AA = CreateAA(9) => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

is there any easy method? Or have to loop and init value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create array with sequence of integers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588787/how-to-create-array-with-sequence-of-integers-in-c)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can avail the functionality of IEnumerable.

```
int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, X+1).ToArray();
```

This will create a IEnumerable List for you and `.ToArray()` will satisfy your int array need.

So for X=9 in your case it would generate the array for `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` (as you need)

Answer (score 11):

Using `Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray()` is very concise but if you want to create a very large array the `ToArray` extension method will have to collect the numbers into a buffer that will have to be reallocated multiple times. On each reallocation the contents of the buffer is copied to the new larger buffer. .NET uses a strategy where the size of the buffer is doubled on each reallocation (and the initial buffer has four items).

So if you want to avoid multiple reallocations of the buffer you need to create the array in advance:

```
int[] aa = new int[10];
for (var i = 0; i < aa.Length; i += 1)
  aa[i] = i;
```

This is the most efficient way of initializing the array.

However, if you need an array of say 100,000,000 consecutive numbers then you should look at a design where you don't have to keep all the numbers in an array to avoid the impact of the memory requirement. `IEnumerable<int>` is very useful for this purpose because you don't have to allocate the entire sequence but can produce it while you iterate and that is exactly what `Enumerable.Range` does. So avoiding the array of consecutive numbers in the first place may be even better than thinking about how to create it.

Answer (score 7):

Why make a function when it is already there.

For this specific example, use

```
int[] AA = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();
```

where `0 is the starting value` and `10 (X + 1) is the length of array`

So a general one applicable to all

```
int[] AA = Enumerable.Range(0, X + 1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Should be `Enumerable.Range(0, X+1)` since the second parameter is `Count`

Comment: Note: If `X` is `9`, then you need to use `Enumerable.Range(0, X + 1)` to get the numbers from 0 to 9.

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Right. It needs a `.ToArray()` also.

Answer (score 2):

with function and loop:

```
static int[] f(int X)
{
    int[] a = new int[X+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        a[i] = i;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: more optimised answers are posted above.

Comment: @vaibhav More concise answers for sure using `Enumerable.Range`. Will that necessarily be more optimised? That said, this code doesn't compile.

Comment: my question @David, why would one create and call a function when there is pre-defined code written for that purpose?

Comment: @vaibhav I certainly would not. I would use `Enumerable.Range`. I just don't think that it is necessarily more efficient that the approach here.

Comment: @David, Martin gave a very useful insight on the usability purpose of the code!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is a function that creates an array.

I made it a bit more versatile by having parameters for the min and max value, i.e. `CreateArray(0, 9)` returns `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`.

```
static int[] CreateArray(int min, int max) {
  int[] a = new int[max - min + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
    a[i] = min + i;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To initialize try this

```
int x = 10;
Enumerable.Range(0, x)
          .Select((v, i) => v + i).ToArray();
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, but still led me to a nice solution. This code will return [0,2,4,... 18]. The `Select()` is not necessary, Range itself already returns [0,1,2,3,.. 9]