# Getting random numbers from a list of integers

Tags: c#, random, int

If I have a list of integers:

```
List<int> myValues = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } );
```

How would I get 3 random integers from that list?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.dotnetperls.com/random)

Comment: did you ever try to solve it? did you ever search on google?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get random values from array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297853/how-to-get-random-values-from-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: One note. This forum is not to put your homework questions and have the world answering it in your place... ok?

Comment: @ncourcy84 What's your basis for assuming this is homework?

Comment: @ncourcy84 I agree with you but the problem is that people answers this kind of homework questions anyway

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One simple way:

```
Random r = new Random();
IEnumerable<int> threeRandom = myValues.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).Take(3);
```

The better way: [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle):

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.Shuffle(new Random());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (rng == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("rng");

        return source.ShuffleIterator(rng);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> ShuffleIterator<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
    {
        List<T> buffer = source.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Count; i++)
        {
            int j = rng.Next(i, buffer.Count);
            yield return buffer[j];

            buffer[j] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
}
```

how you use it:

```
IEnumerable<int> threeRandom = myValues.Shuffle().Take(3);
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way would be something like this:

```
var r = new Random();
var myValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; // Will work with array or list
var randomValues = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
    .Select(e => myValues[r.Next(myValues.Length)]);
```

But a better method, if you want to ensure there are no duplicates is to use a shuffling algorithm, like the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), then take the first 3 items:

```
public static T[] Shuffle<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    var result = items.ToArray();
    var r = new Random();
    for (int i = items.Length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        int j = r.Next(i);
        var t = result[j];
        result[j] = result[i - 1];
        result[i - 1] = t;
    }

    return result;
}

var myValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; // Will work with any enumerable
var randomValues = myValues.Shuffle().Take(3);
```

Comment: But since permutations are randomly generated, they will repeat . What if I want to get all the permutations for a n digit number and save it somewhere. ?

Answer (score 3):

or this:

```
myList.OrderBy(x => Guid.newGuid()).Take(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530362/1654818) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10681905/1654818) can lead you to the following:

```
var rand = new Random();
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 6).OrderBy(i => rand.Next()).ToList();
```

In this case `1` is the starting value (inclusive) and `6` is the number of integers to generate.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of doing it! A simple google can fetch you hundreds of answers.  However, you can do this!

```
myList.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get the number:

```
int k = 3; // items to select
var items = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 });
var selected = new List<int>();
var neededItem = k;
var availableItem = items.Count;
var rand = new Random();
while (selected.Count < k) {
   if( rand.NextDouble() < neededItem / availableItem ) {
      selected.Add(items[availableItem-1])
      neededItem--;
   }
   availableItem--;
}
```

Comment: This can select the same item more than once.  Also, there's no need to get a random double and manipulate it, just use `Next` to get a random int between two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] x = {1,2,3,4};

string result =  Convert.ToString(x[(new Random()).Next(4)]);
```