# Randomly fill list with four different numbers

Tags: c#, random

I've got a list `(randomRotationVoidList)` that needs to be filled with four different numbers `(90, 180, 270, 360)` in a random order, e. g. `[270, 180, 180, 90, ...]`. All I've found so far will generate a list with random numbers between a certain range.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt

Comment: @jspcal items could appear multiple times here `[270, 180, 180, 90, ...]` e.g. `180`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530306/getting-random-numbers-from-a-list-of-integers

Comment: Pick through random index and remove from the source list

Comment: `var rnd = new Random(); randomRotationVoidList = randomRotationVoidList.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList()` - it's best to define `rnd` as a class-level field though to avoid issues with possible duplicated values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sample for 200 numbers

```
Random _rnd = new Random();
int[] input = { 90, 180, 270, 360 }; // dictionary of available numbers
List<int> result = Enumerable.Range(0, 200).Select(x => input[_rnd.Next(0, input.Length)]).ToList();
```

Another approach if the number pattern is fixed to `x * 90`

```
Random _rnd = new Random();
List<int> result = Enumerable.Range(0, 200).Select(x => 90 * _rnd.Next(1, 5)).ToList();
```

Comment: I would call the second approach "more generic".

Comment: @Enigmativity nah.. it's less generic in the sense that it is hardcoded and computes.  result will be `int` whereas first one can result in whatever type is in array.

Comment: My view is that it doesn't use a hard-coded array. It's more generic in that it uses a formula rather than a specific array.

Comment: @Enigmativity but you could replace that array with any type of array of a varaible length e.g. `public static IEnumerable<T> GetRandomList<T>(T[] dictinary, int entries)` so it could be reused for other purposes - and that's the definition of _generic_

Comment: well.. it isn't going to be out of bounds, if that is a worry.. but think of the same sample code but with a different array type: `string[] input = { "90", "180", "270", "360" }` .. we mean `Type` generic ..

Comment: Likewise `public static IEnumerable<T> GetRandomList<T>(Func<T> dictinary, int entries)`

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't really want to make a discussion board out of this, but if you're going to pass `Func<T>` into `Select` you cannot guarantee a random behavior, since that would have to be defined in the delegate you're passing.  Anyhow, it's good answer.