# Using Loops in ComboBox Items in another Method

Tags: c#

I. This is the part of the code in the C# form

```
this.cbDay.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.cbDay.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.cbDay.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            });//items from a loop in another class and method.
```

II. This is my method in another class

```
namespace StudentRegistrationApplication
public class loopComboBoxSelection
{
    public loopComboBox(int start, int finsh)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < finsh; i++)
        {
            ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "Item " + i;
            item.Value = i;
            ModDown.Items.Add(item);
        }
            
    }
}
```

III. I want to call the loop method that will generate items from 1 to 100. For this question, what is the syntax?

```
    this.cbDay.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
                this.cbDay.FormattingEnabled = true;
                this.cbDay.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
                "1"
                "2"
                "3"
                "4"
                "5"});
```

Comment: `this.cbDay.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Cast<object>().ToArray());`. No need for a loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a sequence of integers in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588787/how-to-create-a-sequence-of-integers-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You should be binding the data to the `ComboBox`, e.g.

```cs
cbDay.DisplayMember = nameof(ComboBoxItem.Text);
cbDay.ValueMember = nameof(ComboBoxItem.Value);
cbDay.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(startValue, endValue - startValue + 1)
                             .Select(i => new ComboBoxItem {Text = $"Item {i}", Value = i})
                             .ToArray();
```

The `Text` values will then be displayed in the control and, when the user makes a selection, you can get the corresponding `Value` from the `SelectedValue` property of the control.

Note that you don't have to use LINQ to create the list but it's the binding part that's important. By setting the `DataSource`, you're able to get a specific property value from the `SelectedValue` rather than just the same as you'd get from `SelectedItem`.